# Struggling to create replace method for linked list

Tags: java, string, methods, linked-list, nodes

I have a linked list of names ie:(Mark, Matt, Marten, Brian, Matt) For my project I am trying to create a method where you replace one data with another and return the number of replacements.

Here were our insturctions

- int replace( String oldData, String newData ) – **replaces all 
  occurrences of oldData with newData and returns the number of replacements made 
  (how many times oldData was found in the list).**

How do I replace strings in a linked list and return the number of replacements made?

---

EDIT: This is what I have tried after reviewing @LuiggiMendoza's answer:

```
   public int replace(String oldData, String newData )
     {
     int count = 0;
     StringNode tmp = head;
     while( tmp->next) is not null
     {
       if tmp->data equals to oldData
     {  
         tmp->data = newData
           count = count + 1;
     }
       tmp = tmp->next
     }
       return count;
     }
```

Comment: What i'm going to end up doing is have matt replaced with matthew

Comment: You've tagged this question [tag:java], but there's no `->` operator in Java.

Comment: There's no `is not null` or `equals to` in Java either.  I think you're writing a hodgepodge of Java, C++, and SQL.

Comment: i was getting help from Luiggi Mendoza and this was what i came up with so far, i'm still tweaking with it

Comment: I've been trying to look for examples of a replace method but cant find any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have tag it as java. But few syntax are not support for java.

```
public int replace(String oldData, String newData )
{
     int count = 0;
     StringNode tmp = head;
     while( tmp != null)
     {
       if(tmp.data.equals(oldData)
       {  
         tmp.data = newData;
         count = count + 1;
       }
       tmp = tmp.next;
     }
     return count;

   }
```

Try this code in java. It should work. If the data is your own class, you have to override the equals method. Since it is string, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the nodes of your linked list, check if the data contained in the element is equals to `oldData` and replace it by `newData`. Also, use an `int counter` to know how many nodes were updated.

Here's a pseudocode:

```
int counter = 0
Node tmp = head
while tmp->next is not null
    if tmp->data equals to oldData
        tmp->data = newData
        counter = counter + 1
    end if
    tmp = tmp->next
end while
return counter
```

Comment: I'm not understanding your pseudocode, what is tmp?

Comment: @user3408408 replaced `<-` by `=` (assignment). Hope it is more readable now.

Comment: @user3408408 well, that's your homework. If I post the relevant code, then I would be doing the homework and you won't be able to learn :)

Comment: True haha just havent been finding anything in my book to  help

Comment: Do you know of anywhere where I could find more on this like if there are examples of it